# Why @(NO) isn't kind of class NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, class, types, boolean

I have a weird behavior which seem due to some intern cooking in iOS.

When I do :

```
id data1 = @(NO);
if ([data1 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    // doesn't come here.
}
```

But with `@(YES)` it work perfectly.

First I would like to understand why. Second, I would like to know what you would do in my case ? (Since id can be also text).

**Answer :**

Indeed, @(NO) is a kind a class NSNumber, and my problem was due to some other mistake.

Comment: Is that your exact code? I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's not, in fact my value is stored in a `NSDictionary`, then i extract it with `mydict[@"data1"]` which I pass in a method which ask for an `id` type and then I do my `[data1 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]`. I just didn't wanted to copy the whole thing, but indeed the `NSDictionnary` can have an impact I suppose.

Comment: Then you should NSLog what `mydict[@"data1"]` actually returned. It might be `nil`, or a string or something else that is not a number.

Comment: I did this `NSLog(@"%@ -- %@   (%@ || %@)", data1, data2, [data1 class], [data2 class]);` it returns me `0 -- 1   (__NSCFBoolean || __NSCFBoolean)`. When data1 is `@(NO)` and data2 is `@(YES)` or `@NO` and `@YES`.

Comment: Ok, I saw my mistake which was somewhere else. But I learned lots of things, thank to everyone ! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `@NO` and `@YES` for `NSNumber` instances that represent `NO` and `YES`.

Both `[@(NO) class]` and `[@(YES) class]` give `__NSCFBoolean`.

And `[@NO class]` and `[@YES class]` give `__NSCFBoolean` as well.

And in all four cases a check against `isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]` returned true.

Comment: I did use, but indeed, it's the same result.
It looks good about `__NSCFBoolean`, but I suppose I can't use it since it should be part of private API, isn't ?

Comment: `@NO` and `@(NO)` return the same object, so this should make no difference. And `[data1 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]` *does* return YES for me ...

Comment: I believe `__NSCFBoolean` is a private subclass of `NSNumber`, so it should always return `YES` when you check with `isKindOfClass:` to see if it is an `NSNumber`. However it will return `NO` if you use `isMemberOfClass:` since it isn't that exact class. Apple uses a lot of private subclasses in their frameworks.

Comment: I commented my question for more details.

Comment: @MartinR I updated the answer after confirming a few things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The output is 'number' and 'number' for me. So both of them is NSNumber.

```
    id no = @(NO);
    id yes = @(YES);
    if ([no isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSLog(@"number");
    }if ([yes isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSLog(@"number");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did is called **Boxed expression**
The syntax:

```
@( <expression> )
```

If you want `NSNumber` value of course you should use `@YES` and `@NO` like @maddy said.

but if you interested more about boxed expression take a look at this example (from [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)):

```
// numbers.
NSNumber *smallestInt = @(-INT_MAX - 1);  // [NSNumber numberWithInt:(-INT_MAX - 1)]
NSNumber *piOverTwo = @(M_PI / 2);        // [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(M_PI / 2)]

// enumerated types.
typedef enum { Red, Green, Blue } Color;
NSNumber *favoriteColor = @(Green);       // [NSNumber numberWithInt:((int)Green)]

// strings.
NSString *path = @(getenv("PATH"));       // [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(getenv("PATH"))]
NSArray *pathComponents = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching me, I didn't knew all of them :)