# Why isn't `__NSArrayI` a kind of `[NSArray class]?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So I'm coding up an NSTableView. All is well and fine—until my Control Flow stopped working.

For some reason an array defined as `_permanentItems = @[ @[@"My", @"Permanent"], @[@"Items"] ]`
isn't a kind of `NSArray`.

Why might this be?

For context—it does work for `NSNumber` [Why @(NO) isn't kind of class NSNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633179/why-no-isnt-kind-of-class-nsnumber)

[image: ActiveItems]
[image: __NSArray]
[image: NSArray]

Comment: Please don't show (just) pictures of code. There's nothing here to copy and paste to test your code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `isKindOfClass` works on instances:

> YES if the receiver is an instance of aClass or an instance of any class that inherits from aClass, otherwise NO.

The type of `itemClass` itself is a metatype, and that isn't a kind of NSArray. What you meant here was:

```
if ([item isKindOfClass: arrayClass]) { ... }
     ^^^^
```

If you need to work entirely in classes and don't have an instance, then you can use `+isSubclassOfClass:` instead:

```
if ([itemClass isSubclassOfClass: arrayClass])) { ... }
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```